# MongoDb Map<K, V> codec - Maps MUST have string keys FIX

Tags: java, mongodb, codec, bson, quarkus-panache

While using the mongo DB driver, got a really silly exception `Maps MUST have string keys, found class Enum instead`.
I have found many issues like [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2620) where others failed like me.

I can't really understand why the mondoDb driver does not encode the known key types like the values.
My wish would be that the mongoDB driver fixes this issue and also that the Frameworks like Quarkus could just provide a fix for that like me.
For all others, feel free to contribute and cleanup my hack as I am sure It can be done better.

Answer (score 1):

So I created the following hack, since my debug time and patience is really limited and I want to continue working instead of endless debugging others code

**CODEC:**

```java
import org.bson.BsonDocument;
import org.bson.BsonDocumentWriter;
import org.bson.BsonReader;
import org.bson.BsonType;
import org.bson.BsonWriter;
import org.bson.codecs.Codec;
import org.bson.codecs.DecoderContext;
import org.bson.codecs.EncoderContext;
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException;
import org.bson.json.JsonReader;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MapCodec<K, T> implements Codec<Map<K, T>> {
    private final Class<Map<K, T>> encoderClass;
    private final Codec<K> keyCodec;
    private final Codec<T> valueCodec;

    MapCodec(final Class<Map<K, T>> encoderClass, final Codec<K> keyCodec, final Codec<T> valueCodec) {
        this.encoderClass = encoderClass;
        this.keyCodec = keyCodec;
        this.valueCodec = valueCodec;
    }

    @Override
    public void encode(final BsonWriter writer, final Map<K, T> map, final EncoderContext encoderContext) {
        try (var dummyWriter = new BsonDocumentWriter(new BsonDocument())) {
            dummyWriter.writeStartDocument();
            writer.writeStartDocument();
            for (final Map.Entry<K, T> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                var dummyId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                dummyWriter.writeName(dummyId);
                keyCodec.encode(dummyWriter, entry.getKey(), encoderContext);
                //TODO: could it be simpler by something like JsonWriter?
                writer.writeName(dummyWriter.getDocument().asDocument().get(dummyId).asString().getValue());
                valueCodec.encode(writer, entry.getValue(), encoderContext);
            }
            dummyWriter.writeEndDocument();
        }
        writer.writeEndDocument();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<K, T> decode(final BsonReader reader, final DecoderContext context) {
        reader.readStartDocument();
        Map<K, T> map = getInstance();
        while (reader.readBsonType() != BsonType.END_OF_DOCUMENT) {
            //TODO: what if the key is not a String aka not wrapped in double quotes?
            var nameReader = new JsonReader("{\"key:\":\"" + reader.readName() + "\"}");
            nameReader.readStartDocument();
            nameReader.readBsonType();
            if (reader.getCurrentBsonType() == BsonType.NULL) {
                map.put(keyCodec.decode(nameReader, context), null);
                reader.readNull();
            } else {
                map.put(keyCodec.decode(nameReader, context), valueCodec.decode(reader, context));
            }
            nameReader.readEndDocument();
        }
        reader.readEndDocument();
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Map<K, T>> getEncoderClass() {
        return encoderClass;
    }

    private Map<K, T> getInstance() {
        if (encoderClass.isInterface()) {
            return new HashMap<>();
        }
        try {
            return encoderClass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new CodecConfigurationException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

**PROVIDER:**

```java
import org.bson.BsonReader;
import org.bson.BsonType;
import org.bson.BsonWriter;
import org.bson.codecs.Codec;
import org.bson.codecs.DecoderContext;
import org.bson.codecs.EncoderContext;
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException;
import org.bson.codecs.pojo.PropertyCodecProvider;
import org.bson.codecs.pojo.PropertyCodecRegistry;
import org.bson.codecs.pojo.TypeWithTypeParameters;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapCodecProvider implements PropertyCodecProvider {

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
    public <T> Codec<T> get(final TypeWithTypeParameters<T> type, final PropertyCodecRegistry registry) {
        if (Map.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getType()) && type.getTypeParameters().size() == 2) {
            return new berlin.yuna.royaltanks.config.db.MapCodec(type.getType(), registry.get(type.getTypeParameters().get(0)), registry.get(type.getTypeParameters().get(1)));
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class MapCodec<T> implements Codec<Map<String, T>> {
        private final Class<Map<String, T>> encoderClass;
        private final Codec<T> codec;

        MapCodec(final Class<Map<String, T>> encoderClass, final Codec<T> codec) {
            this.encoderClass = encoderClass;
            this.codec = codec;
        }

        @Override
        public void encode(final BsonWriter writer, final Map<String, T> map, final EncoderContext encoderContext) {
            writer.writeStartDocument();
            for (final Map.Entry<String, T> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                writer.writeName(entry.getKey());
                if (entry.getValue() == null) {
                    writer.writeNull();
                } else {
                    codec.encode(writer, entry.getValue(), encoderContext);
                }
            }
            writer.writeEndDocument();
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, T> decode(final BsonReader reader, final DecoderContext context) {
            reader.readStartDocument();
            Map<String, T> map = getInstance();
            while (reader.readBsonType() != BsonType.END_OF_DOCUMENT) {
                if (reader.getCurrentBsonType() == BsonType.NULL) {
                    map.put(reader.readName(), null);
                    reader.readNull();
                } else {
                    map.put(reader.readName(), codec.decode(reader, context));
                }
            }
            reader.readEndDocument();
            return map;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<Map<String, T>> getEncoderClass() {
            return encoderClass;
        }

        private Map<String, T> getInstance() {
            if (encoderClass.isInterface()) {
                return new HashMap<>();
            }
            try {
                return encoderClass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                throw new CodecConfigurationException(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For others running into this problem, I've made a public repository based on your solution with added handling of codecs that don't accept BsonString using PropertyEditors: https://github.com/benjamonnguyen/mongodb-bson-codec

Grain of salt, this is my first public "contribution" to the community... all criticisms welcome!