# insert in mongodb a variable of type Map with an Enum as key

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to insert an object in mongodb. But I have an error. The problem is with my Map variable. The mongodb driver can't understand that it must consider the key of the map as being a string and not a class Enum and I don't know how to make it understand or set this up

My configuration for taking into account the POJO

```
ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString( "mongodb://localhost:27017" );
    CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build());
    CodecRegistry codecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(), pojoCodecRegistry);

    MongoClientSettings clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
            .codecRegistry(codecRegistry)
            .build();
    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(clientSettings);
```

My POJO

```
public class Business {
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    public final String id;
    public final InterMyType interMyType;

    public Business(String id){
        this.id = id;
        this.interMyType = new InterMyType(false);
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public InterMyType getInterMyType() {
        return interMyType;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Business business = (Business) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, business.id) && Objects.equals(interMyType, business.interMyType);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, interMyType);
    }
}
```

My Enum class

```
public enum MyTypeEnum {
    RULE, TEST
}
```

My InterMyType class

```
public class InterMyType{

    private final Map<MyTypeEnum, Boolean> interaction = new HashMap<>();

    public  InterMyType(Boolean result){
        stream(MyTypeEnum.values()).forEach(myTypeEnum -> this.interaction.put(myTypeEnum,result));
    }

    public Map<MyTypeEnum, Boolean> getInteraction() {
        return interaction;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        InterMyType that = (InterMyType) o;
        return Objects.equals(interaction, that.interaction);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(interaction);
    }
}
```

When I want to insert my Pojo into mongoDb, I get this error

```
2021-08-16 12:59:39 ERROR central:127 - org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException
org.bson.codecs.pojo.AutomaticPojoCodec.encode(AutomaticPojoCodec.java:53)
org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:63)
org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:29)
```

and it's because of my Map varible, because when I put a String in the key, it works. I would like to know how to solve this if there is someone who has already encountered this problem or knows how to do it please

When I look at what I have in my object before insertion, it is what I want to insert

```
RULE => false
TEST => false
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the rest of your exception stacktrace?

Comment: I put it in a comment below

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67849754/mongodb-mapk-v-codec-maps-must-have-string-keys-fix) solution. I created an almost similar class and added my class to the CodecRegistry of the mongoDB driver. If this helps someone who has a similar problem.
For the documentation, you will have to follow [this](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.11/bson/pojos/#default-configuration)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

My  exception stacktrace:

```
2021-08-17 12:12:37 ERROR central:127 - org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException
org.bson.codecs.pojo.AutomaticPojoCodec.encode(AutomaticPojoCodec.java:53)
org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:29)
com.mongodb.operation.BulkWriteBatch$WriteRequestEncoder.encode(BulkWriteBatch.java:385)
com.mongodb.operation.BulkWriteBatch$WriteRequestEncoder.encode(BulkWriteBatch.java:375)
org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:63)
org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:29)
com.mongodb.internal.connection.BsonWriterHelper.writeDocument(BsonWriterHelper.java:75)
com.mongodb.internal.connection.BsonWriterHelper.writePayload(BsonWriterHelper.java:59)
com.mongodb.internal.connection.BsonWriterHelper.writePayloadArray(BsonWriterHelper.java:51)
com.mongodb.internal.connection.SplittablePayloadBsonWriter.writeEndDocument(SplittablePayloadBsonWriter.java:56)
org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.encode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:118)
org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.encode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:41)
com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandMessage.addDocumentWithPayload(CommandMessage.java:183)
com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandMessage.encodeMessageBodyWithMetadata(CommandMessage.java:167)
com.mongodb.internal.connection.RequestMessage.encode(RequestMessage.java:138)
com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandMessage.encode(CommandMessage.java:61)
com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:248)
com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceive(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:99)
com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceive(DefaultConnectionPool.java:450)
com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.execute(CommandProtocolImpl.java:72)
com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:218)
com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:269)
com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:131)
com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.executeCommand(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:435)
com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.executeBulkWriteBatch(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:261)
com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.access$700(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:72)
com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$1.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:205)
com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$1.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:196)
com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withReleasableConnection(OperationHelper.java:501)
com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:196)
com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:71)
com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:206)
com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:1048)
com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeInsertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:498)
com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:482)
com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:476)
com.spideo.central.dao.cache.BetterCachedDao2.lambda$save$0(BetterCachedDao2.java:166)
java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
java.util.Collections$2.tryAdvance(Collections.java:4719)
java.util.Collections$2.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:4727)
java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
```